# How to refresh data on every sunday

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

How to refresh the data on every Sunday, if user forgot Sunday and open the application on Monday or Tuesday or one month the the data should be refresh.

```
-(void) checkRefreshGoals:(int)sectionIndex rowIndex:(int)rowIndex
{
    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString * currentDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString * initialNotificationDate = [formatter stringFromDate:refreshDate];
    NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
    NSDate *refreshDate = [formatter dateFromString:initialNotificationDate];

    if ([refreshDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
        isGoalsRefreshed = NO;
    }
    else if ([refreshDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
        if (sameDay == YES)
        {
            isGoalsRefreshed = YES;
            [self refreshDataOnSunday:sectionIndex rowIndex:rowIndex];
        }
        else if (noOfDaysCount > 7)
        {
            isGoalsRefreshed = YES;
            [self refreshDataOnSunday:sectionIndex rowIndex:rowIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            isGoalsRefreshed = NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"dates are the same");
        isRefreshed = NO;
    }
}
```

Initial stage its not refreshing since my start date is on Thursday and when i skip the Sunday and directly going to Monday its not refreshing the data.

Comment: You don't show how you are setting `refreshDate` or `noOfDaysCount`. You could store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` to see if the app has ever run before. If it hasn't then perform the refresh regardless of time. If thats not what you are asking, think so more info/code would help others to possible answer

Comment: Generate an array of sunday dates, and then check those dates regularly. If one date is passed/matched update the dataset and also remove that date from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need only two tools to get this done: (1) the ability to generate and NSDate representing the most recent Sunday....

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarOptions options = NSCalendarMatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits | NSCalendarSearchBackwards;
NSDate *mostRecentSunday = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date] matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday value:1 options:options];
```

(2) knowledge of when refresh was last done, something like...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *mostRecentRefresh = [defaults objectForKey:@"mostRecentRefresh"];
```

The procedure, whenever the app wakes, is to get the most recent Sunday and the most recent refresh date.  If the most recent Sunday is the later date, then do the refresh and record the current date as the last refresh date.  Simply...

```
if (mostRecentSunday == [mostRecentSunday laterDate:mostRecentRefresh]) {
    // do refresh
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"mostRecentRefresh"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback:  For Me data is refreshed on every Sunday.  new problem is when i missed is Sunday to open the application its should refresh the data on next or when opened the application from missed Sunday.

Comment: Are you sure?  The condition I've suggested is true whenever the app is opened on or after a sunday following a refresh.